# Returning True or False from find command

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, find

I need to check if a given file, with specific filename, exists in a directory (including sub-directories), and then perform an action if it exists, and another if not.
Is there a way to use `find` command, returning True or False, as a condition for an `if` statement? I'm struggling to get it to work, but I don't know if it's just a problem of syntax or if there is a better way to approach the problem.

My specific problem is that I have a folder with lots of pictures in it, altogether. And I have a second folder where part of the same pictures are organized by subject on subfolders.
So I want to delete, in the first folder, all the pictures that already are in the second folder.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
for file in "/first/folder"/*; do
   filename=`basename $file`

   if [find /second/folder -name $filename]
   then
      rm $file
   fi
done
```

Comment: Add an input and sample output. Also https://shellcheck.net for validating scripts

Comment: Do you really need `find` in this case? Are there multiple layers of subfolders under `/second/folder`? If not, then you could use `if [ -f /second/folder/$filename ]`. Your `for` loop is missing a `done` at the end by the way.

Comment: You're right @lurker, I don't need to use `find`. So, I don't have multiple layers, just one or two. `if [ -f /second/folder/$filename ]` won't work because the files are not in that folder, but in sub-folders in that. But `if [ -f /second/folder/*/$filename ]` will work for the first layer, but not for the second or others... There is probably a way to make it work for all layers under it...

Comment: If you have one or two layers depending, then you do have multiple layers and there's nothing wrong with using `find` in that case

Comment: Instead of `if [find /second/folder -name $filename] ; then rm $file ; fi` you should just have `find /second/folder -name $filename -exec rm {} \;`.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know if it's just a problem of syntax or if there is a better way to approach the problem.

Yes there are syntax errors in your program. But there is no need to run `find` over and over for each file. Here is a more effective approach:

```
find /second/folder -type f -exec bash -c '
for fpath in "${@/#*\//"/first/folder/"}"; do
  if [[ -f $fpath ]]; then
    delete+=("$fpath")
  fi
done
echo rm -- "${delete[@]}"' _ {} +
```

Drop `echo` if its output looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Your block for `if [ find ... ]` is only going to execute once depending upon the overall execution result of `find`. `find` supports an option to execute a command on matches:

```
for file in "/first/folder"/* ; do
   filename=$(basename "$file")
   find /second/folder -name $filename -exec rm {} \;
fi
```